Identify these SMD component inside a Fluke 62 marked "C7VHS" and "1301"
These componente are inside a Fluxe 62 Mini Infrared Thermometer that is not turning on.
There are only these two components that I can't identify anyhow.
First one is a SOT-23 marked as "C7VHS". Its mask is "Q1", and all other "Q's" are transistors - all of them being pre biased BJT's, e.g., DIODES DDTA114EE.
I tried all catalogs I could find, alldatasheet.com, of course google, but I couldn't find it. It is most likely just another pre biased BJT, there should be nothing special about it, but I can't find it and I need to know it so I can finish my hypothesis. 
As a side note, one can't test these pre biased BJTs using a regular DMM, at least not the ones that come with higher value internal resistors.
Here are some pictures of it:




The second one is marked "1301", and based on its position and surrounding components, it is surely a step up converter, since the Fluke 62 operates from a single 1.5V AA battery.
Weirdly, Linear Technologies (Analog) has a step up DC DC converter, LT1301, that has the "1301" marking, but it only comes in 8-pin flavor. And this one clearly has only 6-pins:


EDIT: After nanash1's reply, I submitted a ticket to Infineon. The markings indeed correspond to a IRLML6302:


did you check the battery?

@jsotola where's that damn laughing emoji button when you need it?

Yes, I did check it.

Q1 is probably an Infineon IRLML6302 p-channel MOSFET.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Thank you. I have a couple of follow up questions. Looking at the the datasheet, the only letter that has a line above it is the week, indicating that the chip is lead-free. It can also be seen here: https://www.irf.com/package/partmarking.pdf . In the pictures I took, there are lines below the first 4 characters. However, this matches the picture from LCSC. I could not find an online image of an actual chip to confirm which one is right, so I am inclined to consider the datasheet the correct reference, for obvious reasons. Have you worked with them before or have one available for checking?

Also, may I ask how you found this marking correspondence? I mean, you can't just look the marking on LCSC, right? So the same question above, have you worked with this part before?

This comment has been removed because I placed it on the wrong reply :)

@tfm I found the part because I know Infineon IRLML* parts have this 5 character marking style with lines over and/or under some of them. As far as I can tell, the number of lines varies and doesn't exactly follow what's shown in the datasheet. LCSC is reputable distributor, so I'm pretty sure that their picture is of a genuine Infineon part. You can also use LCSC to look at other mosfets of the IRLML series. You'll find that number and position of the lines varies a bit.

I submitted a ticket to Infineon. The markings indeed correspond to a IRLML6302 and I've added this information to the question. Thank you.

The second could be a PowTech PT1301 step up converter, which claims to start from 0.8 V, which sounds perfect for one battery setups. Found via: SManuals
PowTech now seems to be called or is part of CR Micro.

Image credit: lcsc.com

Thank you! This is most likely a match! I tried to use the Smanuals website, yesterday and today, but I just keep getting  “This site can't be reached”. There is not even cache/cookies, and I tried different browsers. Maybe it is unavailable to my region??

Could be, or if you connect via an enterprise network, that it is blocked there, which is also quite common these days.

I am torn here, I just can't choose 2 correct answers. So I have upvoted yours, since it was a bit later. Your reply was very helpful, I hope I can make it up a next time or contribute to one of your questions! :)

@tfm the correct solution is to ask two questions next time for two separate parts. They can still be mentioned and thus linked. But no worries.

I see. Fair point. Thank you.
